# Accessing EC2 Instance via Internet Security Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, wiki.js

I have configured an EC2 instance and I am now trying to install an open source app ([Wiki.js](https://wiki.js.org/)). One of the steps (visible [here under configuration](https://docs.requarks.io/wiki/install#alternative-npm-method)) requires me to navigate to http://localhost:3000/ but replace localhost with the IP address of my server. I have tried this multiple times and tried different variations of security groups for the EC2 Instance but nothing seems to work. Currently the inbound rules are set to the following:

1)

- Type: HTTP
- Protocol: TCP
- Port Range: 80
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

2)

- Type: HTTPS
- Protocol: TCP
- Port Range: 443
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

3)

- Type: SSH
- Protocol: TCP
- Port Range: 22
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

I'm not sure what the problem could be. Are these security settings wrong? Am I using the wrong IP address? I am coping the address directly from the console under Iv4 Public IP.

**EDIT:**

Could it have something to do with the route table or subnet? If so it doesn't appear to be possible to edit those via the console. Would I need create a new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you open port 3000 for the EC2 instance ?

I think the application requires you to access port 3000. But you don't configure that security group.

Comment: That produced a different result. Instead of the web browser saying the IP address took to long to connect, it now says the IP address refused to connect.

Comment: Never mind. It is working I think my connection to the instance had just timed out.

Comment: I was able to complete the configuration process after adding port 3000, but now when I try to access the EC2 instance via the browser it says "this site can't be reached" do you know why this could be?

Comment: I also added access via port 9000 and that didn't fix it.

Comment: @BenNalle Did you successfully see the site top page after all ?

Comment: Yes it worked I was able to load the configuration guide, but once the configuration process was finished I couldn't access the server via the browser.

Comment: It means you resolved the network issue. Next, you need to resolve application problem.

Comment: Why would the application work and then not work? What makes you think it is a problem with the application? Does this narrow it down to an application problem: I installed Apache on the server and when I visited the IP address via the browser the Apache page loaded. Does that mean it can't be a problem with the server?

Comment: Is there any clue to clarify the problem ?

Comment: I didn't know if me being able to access the Apache page via the browser narrowed it down to being a problem with the application and not with the server? As far as it what problem it is with the application I can't figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166464/discussion-between-ben-nalle-and-hiropon).